# writing to a program into input stream

Tags: automation

I am using oracle wallet to store the oracle database passwords,
the batch file to create the wallet asks for password when you run it.
is there any way to modify the batch file , and provide the password before hand

so that i can avoid inputtting the password every time i run that.

so to generalize the problem, is there any way i can write to input stream of another program.

so that i can avoid prompts from my automation scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pipe operator "|" to redirect the standard output stream of one program into the input stream of another.  I works both on unix and windows platforms.

In your example you would have a script doing just

```
echo mypassword
```

and you would run this from the command line:

```
myscript | wallet
```

I assume that your script would be called myscript.bat, and the wallet program wallet.exe, change these accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the password in a text file like password.txt

and you can run like

myprogram.exe < password.txt

if the program accepts two inputs then type the second input in the second line of the text file.